# Python Bar Chart y-axis with value mean

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having issues using Pandas and Pyplot to produce a bar chart. I am trying to use the mean of a column for the bar chart y-axis / bar height with the x-axis being a bar for each gender.

I can plot a bar chart with gender displaying correctly by call the column with gender as the x, but when I call just the column with fare as the y, the plot fails. When I call df.mean() of the fare column, the bars plot but at the same height (total mean for fare).

What I am trying to do is to get the bar height = mean of the fare for that gender.

```
import pandas as pd                                 # import pandas package (install via settings first)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt                # import pyplot package (install via settings first)

# train_df pulls from a .CSV file

train_embarkS_survive = train_df.filter(['Sex', 'Embarked', 'Fare', 'Survived'])    
train_embarkS_survive = train_embarkS_survive.query('Embarked == "S" and Survived == 1')

plt.figure('Q13: ')
plt.bar(train_embarkS_survive['Sex'], train_embarkS_survive['Fare'].mean(axis=0)) 
plt.xlabel('Sex')                                                
plt.ylabel('Fare')                                               
plt.title('Embarked = S | Survived = 1')    
plt.show()
```

The plt.bar of my filtered dataframe using the 'Sex' column (categorical variable with male, female unique values) and the mean of the 'Fare' Column produces a bar chart with equal bar heights (the mean of all fares, not just those for each category male, female).

[image]

In actuality, the fare mean for female = 44.60, male = 30.37. How can I get these calculated means as the respective bar heights?

I have tried using groupby() but plt.bar would not accept

```
train_embarkS_survive.groupby(['Sex']).mean()
```

For the y-axis argument.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data Data is the test.csv located on the site. omitted from my code is the dataframe I first used (for other purposes, named train_df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were in the right direction by using the groupby function. I'd save the interim dataframe before plotting the bar chart. The function `bar` of the `pyplot` module takes the series for x and y axis, you need to pass them separately, i.e. here they are represented by the index (`'female'` and `'male'`) and the aggregated result of Fare mean, which is saved in the column `'Fare'`.

```
df_mean=train_embarkS_survive.groupby(['Sex']).agg({'Fare':'mean'})
plt.bar(df_mean.index,df_mean['Fare'])
plt.show()
```

The bar chart shows the mean accordingly for male and female.
[image: Bar chart for fare mean by sex]